# div hover another one absolute center jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to display a div.text (red in image) hover an div.image (black) in absolute center. I think about a javascript that get the size of each image than give a css to the div.text. It’s for a WP so each image have a different height (and width sometime) and it have to get the size for all of them.

Thank you very much.

[image: http://jeandetremontels.fr/images/stack.png]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Well... it's possible to make a `<div>` with a `background-image` instead of a `<img>`. So, the red `<div>` would be styled to be at the center of the parent `<div>`.

Comment: I’ve try the css but like every image have a different height it's not the thing i’m looking for. I know a little bit about javascript (learning) and i know that i can retrieve a #div height and width, then add a css for the text#div absolute => top:50%; margin-top: -(div#image'height/2); left: 50%; margin-left: - (div#image'width/2);

Answer (score 1):

A quick way is to create a table with one cell, vertical/horizontal centering, set style to "display: none;", size the table according to .height() and .width() of the image, and make the table absolute position with a high z-index, over the image.  Then set up a hover behavior on the image that displays the table above it, and hides again on hover off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery UI positioning plugin.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/

```
$("#MyDiv").position({
  my : "center center",
  at : "center center",
  of : "#MyImage"
});
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/QYH8w/1/

Comment: Doesn't the div he wants to display need to be hidden first?  That looks like a limitation in the plugin.

Comment: Nope. I've never had to hide the div before I used it.

Comment: I don’t need any div to be hidden, that look cool ! i m trying :-)

Comment: This won't hide your divs or images.  This will place your div at the center of your image.  Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/QYH8w/1/